# Compare count result

Tags: hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

In my database, I have publications and each publication can have zero or more pages, which are stored in another table. When selecting them, I either want to get all publications or only the ones with at least one page. The following criteria query is not working because of this error: `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: p`

```
Criteria c = Utils.getSession().createCriteria(Publication.class);

if(!showEmptyPublications)
{
    ProjectionList pl = Projections.projectionList();
    pl.add(Projections.count("pages").as("p"));
    c.setProjection(pl);
    c.add(Restrictions.gt("p", 0));
}

c.addOrder(Order.asc("titel"));
publications = c.list();
```

Publication:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Publication` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=47 ;
```

Page:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Page` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `pub_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `FOREIGN_KEY_DICT` (`pub_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6314 ;

ALTER TABLE `Page`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FOREIGN_KEY_PUBLICATION` FOREIGN KEY (`pub_id`)
REFERENCES `Publication` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Publication.java:

```
...
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "publication")
public Set<Page> getPages()
{
    return this.pages;
}

public void setPages(Set<Page> pages)
{
    this.pages = pages;
}
```

Comment: Could you add table definitions (or hibernate mappings)? "[pages] are stored in another table" suggests it is not a simple one table query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following will give you the publications where pages is not empty (means atleast one page is there for that publication):

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Publication.class, "publication");
c.createAlias("publication.pages", "page");
c.add(Restrictions.isNotEmpty("page"));
c.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
```